# Is It possible to connect to socket server using hamachi?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, hamachi

Is It possible?
I wrote a code using socket library.
Everything works fine on local network but when I try to connect using hamachi IP I get [WinError 10060]

Sample of server code:

```
import socket
import threading

def start_server(port, serverip):
    global serverThread, server
    server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((serverip, port))
    serverThread=threading.Thread(target=start)
    serverThread.start()
    
def start():
    global runn
    print("Server został uruchomiony i czeka na połączenie")
    server.listen()
    runn=True
    while runn:
        try:
            con, addres= server.accept()
            print(f"{addres} połączył się")
            users.append(con)
            addreses.append(addres)
            cn= threading.Thread(target=connection, args=(con, addres))
            cn.start()
        except:
            break
```

Sample of client code:

```
def connect_to_server(serverport, serverip):
    global client
    client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    client.connect((serverip, serverport))
```

Comment: This server code doesn't work because `server` is undefined

Comment: I made mistake when I was copying code. Now everything should be fine.

Comment: what is serverip?

Comment: It's IP of server. On localhost It's my local IP and when i try host using hamachi It's IP from hamachi.

Comment: If you use 0.0.0.0 the server will allow connections on any one of the computer's IPs

Comment: It doesn't work either when client try to connect via hamachi IP

Comment: does it work if you use the Hamachi IP on a different computer (also connected to Hamachi)?

Comment: No, It doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of Windows defender. Hamachi has to be added to exceptions in public and private network.